# Subtract to get decimal values in ERC20 Contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I tried to split real and decimal values. 
For eg. 209/100 => 2.09  So i want to store 2 is one variable and 0.09 into another variable. but its return zero always.

```
uint256 realToken = (209/100) ;                    //output 2
uint256 refundToken =   ((209/100) - realToken  )*10**18;   //output is 0
```

refundToken value should be 90000000000000000 but returned 0

Please give suggestion and

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to get the remainder of a division operation:

```
uint division = (209/100); // division == 2
uint modulus = (209%100);  // modulus == 9
```

Your corrected code would look like:

```
uint256 refundToken =   ((209%100)*10**18)/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your second expression for right implementation as:

`uint256 refundToken =   ((209) - realToken*100)*10**18)/100;`

It should work.

Comment: Yeah, we have to multiply first to get the division right.